# .NET Crystal Reports for visual studio 13 ODBC PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, crystal-reports

We use Crystal Reports. Initially built for SQL Server database on OLEDBSQL driver. Data is obtained primarily through stored procedures. They were recently transferred to the MSOLEDBSQL driver by replacing the used driver at runtime ("Provider" property: "MSOLEDBSQL", etc.), the rpt reports themselves did not correct. Works great.

Now we need to transfer part of the reports to PostgreSQL. ODBC was chosen as the driver. And here we ran into a problem.

What succeeded:

1. At runtime, change the driver to ODBC ("Connection String" property: $"PROVIDER=MSDASQL; DRIVER={{PostgreSQL Unicode}}; SERVER={server}; DATABASE={database};", "Database DLL": " crdb_odbc.dll").
   Primitive reports have earned.
2. In the designer, specify a new location for stored procedures on PostgreSQL (technically, of course, this is a function).

Although this moment is optional. We planned to make all the changes in the code, without editing the rpt files.

Problem: when Crystal Reports sees that a PosgreSQL function/SP is specified, it categorically marks all parameters (@) as NOT NULL (EnableNullValue = False). In a PostgreSQL function, the parameters are marked as nullable. Any attempts to pass Nothing/DbNull.Value end with errors like:

> Setpoint and current value types do not match

or

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> HResult=0x80042009
> Message = The types of the parameter field and the current values ​​of the parameter field are not compatible

If you pass any values ​​(for example, an empty string), then the report starts working.

**Question**: how to make Crystal Reports work with PostgreSQL functions and NULL parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't try to change drivers like that in code. You should tweak them in Crystal Reports first. You can point to different databases or different DSNs in code, but the drivers themselves, you should set those in Crystal.